# PHP imagecopymerge source image's background change transparent to black

Tags: php

I need to merge two pictures,
my code is like this:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/big.jpg"); 
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng("small_image/8.png");
$size = getimagesize("small_image/8.png");


imagecopymerge($image, $image1, 400, 30, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], 100);
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($image);
imagedestroy($image1);
```

the frist picture is :

[image]

second is :
[image]

final result not transparent

[image]

Please help!!!Thanks!

new version of code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/big.jpg"); 
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng("small_image/8.png");
$size = getimagesize("small_image/8.png");
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);
imagealphablending($image1, false);
imagesavealpha($image1, true);


imagecopymerge($image, $image1, 400, 30, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], 100);

header('Content-Type: image/gif');


imagegif($image);
imagedestroy($image1);
```

and the result is :
    [image]

Comment: Have you checked out the duplicates that were suggested to you when you wrote the question title (they're in the "Related" column to the right)?

Comment: @Pekka웃,believe me,i tried...but can't find perfect solution..

Comment: You have tried the solutions in the first question in the "related" column and they didn't work? Then you should update your code accordingly to reflect that.

Comment: @Pekka웃,hi i edited my question and result,you can have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..i found a solution now..

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/show01.jpg"); //
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng("small_image/1.png");//
$image3 = imagecreatefromgif("images/carBg.gif");//
$size = getimagesize("small_image/1.png");
$overlay = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 80);

$white = imagecolorallocate($overlay, 229, 229, 229);
imagefilledrectangle($overlay, 0, 0, 80, 80, $white);

imagecolortransparent($overlay,$white);  
     imagecopy($overlay, $image1, (80-$size[0])/2, (80-$size[1])/2, 0, 0,   $size[0],$size[1]);
imagecopymerge($image3, $overlay, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80, 100);


imagecopymerge($image, $image3, 280, 30, 0, 0, 80, 80, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

// and finally, output the result
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```