# imagecopymerge is giving me dark patch

Tags: php, image, gd, imagecreatefrompng

I am trying to merge two images. featured7.png is having a transparent background. But the final image is like below with a dark patch:
[image]

Here is the code: Please help:

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng('images/featured7.png');
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/1.jpg');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
imageColorAllocateAlpha($dest, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 90, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Newly modified code is below: but giving the same result except the small image moved to some more right-center:

```
$img1 = imagecreatefrompng('images/featured7.png');
$img2 = imagecreatefrompng('images/1.jpg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/1.jpg"); //
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng("images/featured7.png");//
$size = getimagesize("images/featured7.png");
$overlay = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 80);
$white = imagecolorallocate($overlay, 229, 229, 229);
imagefilledrectangle($overlay, 0, 0, 80, 80, $white);
imagecolortransparent($overlay,$white);  
imagecopy($overlay, $image1, (80-$size[0])/2, (80-$size[1])/2, 0, 0,   $size[0],$size[1]);
imagecopymerge($image, $image1, 280, 30, 0, 0, 80, 80, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Here are the two images:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem before,and i fond the soluton,please see my question and answer here:

[PHP imagecopymerge source image's background change transparent to black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412686/php-imagecopymerge-source-images-background-change-transparent-to-black)
in you case sample use this:

```
$dit = imagecreatefromjpeg("./dst.jpg"); //
$source = imagecreatefrompng("./source.png");//
$size = getimagesize("./source.png");
imagecopy($dit, $source, 0,0, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1]);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dit);
imagedestroy($dit);
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the code upside, please check.. thnx for your help, please advise me further..

Comment: @Srikanta,if still have problem ,please give me these two images source link

Comment: All images in my local system only, for the small image(featured.png) size is 90*90 and it is a png image with transparent background... for big image the sixe is 500*360 jpg

Comment: @Srikanta,you can post your two images to you question,like my question posted

Comment: I have posted, Please check

Comment: Thanks!! that works for me, I was messing up the source and destination image